# .html no ejecuta lo que he escrito

Tags: javascript

tengo un pequeño problema con un html que estoy practicando. Resulta que estoy tomando un pequeño curso de programación en el cual estamos viendo Html y me ha tocado una "tarea" sobre el comando "if" a modo de práctica, el problema es que he escrito el código, tal cual me ha dicho el profesor, pero al momento de ejecutar el archivo, éste no hace nada, a continuación, dejaré lo que he escrito para que me puedan ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias.

[image: Aqui está]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Ignacio, recuerda agregar tu código como texto y no como imagen, de esta forma la comunidad puede ayudarte de una mejor manera, revisa [ask]. Realiza el [tour] del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad que debes usar es

> [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/length): La propiedad length de un objeto String representa la
>   longitud de una cadena.

```js
var palabra = prompt("Escribe una palabra.");
if (palabra.length > 7){
  document.write("Esta palabra es muy larga.");
}else{
   console.log("longitud aceptada.");
}
```